Problem with Action Control in IRP Cloth Simulation Replay — Model Moves Only Up and Down
I am working on replaying a simulation using the IRP cloth manipulation project from this repository. I'm encountering an issue where the model, instead of moving in a dynamic way towards the table, only moves up and down during the replay. This behavior does not match what I expected from the training phase.
(1:) Below is the link to the project. Checkpoints from there I am trying to render.
https://github.com/real-stanford/irp?tab=readme-ov-file#datasets
The goal of my project is to simulate cloth manipulation actions based on a pre-trained model. I’ve followed the provided instructions and am using the "ClothDeltaDeeplab" network with checkpoint data from a prior training run. The issue arises during replay: the simulation does not perform the intended sequence of actions and instead exhibits only a limited vertical movement, which doesn't look like meaningful cloth manipulation.
I’m trying to figure out where the problem lies — whether it’s the checkpoint, the way actions are applied, or something wrong with the training process itself. My checkpoint is loaded successfully, the rendering context is initialized, and there are no critical runtime errors. Despite these, the behavior is not what I expect: the cloth only moves up and down without advancing towards the intended target.
Training and Checkpoints: I have trained the model using the provided dataset and saved the checkpoints correctly. During the replay phase, I use these checkpoints to control the actions. I expected that the trained model would have learned to execute various actions to manipulate the cloth towards the table.

Actions Logging: I tried modifying the code to save actions into a log file, which I hoped would help me understand what actions were generated. I verified that the actions are logged correctly.

Code Modifications: I've also made changes to the replay script to ensure that it reads the checkpoint and uses the saved actions properly. However, it appears that the model is not using these actions in a way that produces the desired output. It seems as if the model is either stuck or not properly integrating the checkpoint data.

What Happened: Despite all these changes, the result remains the same: the cloth only moves up and down during the simulation replay. I need help understanding why the model isn't moving towards the table as intended and whether there's an issue with the checkpoint, the action control logic, or something else entirely.
Any insights into how I could further debug or fix this would be greatly appreciated!
import os
import torch
import numpy as np
import mujoco
import glfw
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
import logging

# Set up logging for debugging
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

from networks.cloth_delta_deeplab import ClothDeltaDeeplab

class HistoryBuffer:
    def __init__(self, max_length=9):
        self.max_length = max_length
        self.buffer = []

    def append(self, item):
        self.buffer.insert(0, item)
        if len(self.buffer) > self.max_length:
            self.buffer.pop()

    def get_buffer(self):
        return self.buffer[::-1]

def main():
    # Device configuration
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

    # Path to your checkpoint
    checkpoint_path = '/home/triton300se/irp_project/outputs/18-02-26/checkpoints/last.ckpt'

    # Load the model
    try:
        pretrained_model = ClothDeltaDeeplab.load_from_checkpoint(
            checkpoint_path,
            map_location=device
        )
        print("Checkpoint loaded successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading model from checkpoint: {e}")
        return

    pretrained_model.eval()
    pretrained_model.to(device)

    # Access action_sigma from the model
    action_sigma = pretrained_model.hparams.action_sigma
    print(f"action_sigma from model: {action_sigma}")

    # Initialize MuJoCo simulation
    try:
        mujoco_xml_path = '/home/triton300se/irp/assets/mujoco/cloth/cloth.xml'
        model = mujoco.MjModel.from_xml_path(mujoco_xml_path)
        print(f"Number of actuators (model.nu): {model.nu}")

        # Print control ranges to verify they're set correctly
        print(f"Control ranges from model: {model.actuator_ctrlrange}")

        data = mujoco.MjData(model)
        print("Model loaded successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while loading the model: {e}")
        return  # Exit the script if model loading fails

    # Initialize GLFW
    if not glfw.init():
        print("Could not initialize GLFW")
        return

    # Create window and make OpenGL context current
    window = glfw.create_window(800, 600, "MuJoCo Simulation", None, None)
    if not window:
        print("Could not create GLFW window")
        glfw.terminate()
        return
    glfw.make_context_current(window)

    # Initialize MuJoCo rendering context
    try:
        context = mujoco.MjrContext(model, mujoco.mjtFontScale.mjFONTSCALE_150)
        print("Rendering context initialized successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while initializing the rendering context: {e}")
        glfw.terminate()
        return

    # Simulation parameters
    num_steps = 1000

    # Main simulation loop
    for step in range(num_steps):
        # Prepare sample input data for the model
        input_trajectory = torch.randn(1, 9, 256, 256).to(device)
        action_delta = torch.randn(1, 4).to(device)
import os
import torch
import numpy as np
import mujoco
import glfw
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
import logging

# Set up logging for debugging
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

from networks.cloth_delta_deeplab import ClothDeltaDeeplab

class HistoryBuffer:
    def __init__(self, max_length=9):
        self.max_length = max_length
        self.buffer = []

    def append(self, item):
        self.buffer.insert(0, item)
        if len(self.buffer) > self.max_length:
            self.buffer.pop()

    def get_buffer(self):
        return self.buffer[::-1]

def main():
    # Device configuration
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

    # Path to your checkpoint
    checkpoint_path = '/home/triton300se/irp_project/outputs/18-02-26/checkpoints/last.ckpt'

    # Load the model
    try:
        pretrained_model = ClothDeltaDeeplab.load_from_checkpoint(
            checkpoint_path,
            map_location=device
        )
        print("Checkpoint loaded successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading model from checkpoint: {e}")
        return

    pretrained_model.eval()
    pretrained_model.to(device)

    # Access action_sigma from the model
    action_sigma = pretrained_model.hparams.action_sigma
    print(f"action_sigma from model: {action_sigma}")

    # Initialize MuJoCo simulation
    try:
        mujoco_xml_path = '/home/triton300se/irp/assets/mujoco/cloth/cloth.xml'
        model = mujoco.MjModel.from_xml_path(mujoco_xml_path)
        print(f"Number of actuators (model.nu): {model.nu}")

        # Print control ranges to verify they're set correctly
        print(f"Control ranges from model: {model.actuator_ctrlrange}")

        data = mujoco.MjData(model)
        print("Model loaded successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while loading the model: {e}")
        return  # Exit the script if model loading fails

    # Initialize GLFW
    if not glfw.init():
        print("Could not initialize GLFW")
        return

    # Create window and make OpenGL context current
    window = glfw.create_window(800, 600, "MuJoCo Simulation", None, None)
    if not window:
        print("Could not create GLFW window")
        glfw.terminate()
        return
    glfw.make_context_current(window)

    # Initialize MuJoCo rendering context
    try:
        context = mujoco.MjrContext(model, mujoco.mjtFontScale.mjFONTSCALE_150)
        print("Rendering context initialized successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while initializing the rendering context: {e}")
        glfw.terminate()
        return

    # Simulation parameters
    num_steps = 1000

    # Main simulation loop
    for step in range(num_steps):
        # Prepare sample input data for the model
        input_trajectory = torch.randn(1, 9, 256, 256).to(device)
        action_delta = torch.randn(1, 4).to(device)
#Найти как подставлять рандомный значения 
        # Pass the input through the model
        with torch.no_grad():
            output = pretrained_model(input_trajectory, action_delta)

        # Process the model output to compute actions
        # For this example, we'll just use action_delta directly
        action = action_delta.cpu().numpy().flatten()[:model.nu]
        print(f"Step {step}, action before clipping: {action}")

        # Ensure action has correct dimensions
        action = np.asarray(action).flatten()
        if action.shape[0] != model.nu:
            raise ValueError(f"Action dimension mismatch: expected {model.nu}, got {action.shape[0]}")

        # Get control ranges and clip actions
        ctrl_range = model.actuator_ctrlrange.copy()
        print(f"Control ranges: {ctrl_range}")

        action = np.clip(action, ctrl_range[:, 0], ctrl_range[:, 1])
        print(f"Action after clipping: {action}")

        # Apply action to simulation
        data.ctrl[:] = action

        # Step simulation
        try:
            mujoco.mj_step(model, data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred during simulation step: {e}")
            break

        # Check for invalid simulation state
        if np.any(np.isnan(data.qpos)) or np.any(np.isinf(data.qpos)):
            print(f"Invalid qpos detected at step {step}")
            break

        # Render simulation
        if glfw.window_should_close(window):
            break

        # Update scene and render
        viewport_width, viewport_height = glfw.get_framebuffer_size(window)
        viewport = mujoco.MjrRect(0, 0, viewport_width, viewport_height)
        cam = mujoco.MjvCamera()
        opt = mujoco.MjvOption()
        scene = mujoco.MjvScene(model, maxgeom=10000)
        mujoco.mjv_updateScene(model, data, opt, None, cam, mujoco.mjtCatBit.mjCAT_ALL, scene)
        mujoco.mjr_render(viewport, scene, context)
        glfw.swap_buffers(window)
        glfw.poll_events()

    # Clean up
    glfw.terminate()
    print("Simulation completed successfully.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

        # Pass the input through the model
        with torch.no_grad():
            output = pretrained_model(input_trajectory, action_delta)

        # Process the model output to compute actions
        # For this example, we'll just use action_delta directly
        action = action_delta.cpu().numpy().flatten()[:model.nu]
        print(f"Step {step}, action before clipping: {action}")

        # Ensure action has correct dimensions
        action = np.asarray(action).flatten()
        if action.shape[0] != model.nu:
            raise ValueError(f"Action dimension mismatch: expected {model.nu}, got {action.shape[0]}")

        # Get control ranges and clip actions
        ctrl_range = model.actuator_ctrlrange.copy()
        print(f"Control ranges: {ctrl_range}")

        action = np.clip(action, ctrl_range[:, 0], ctrl_range[:, 1])
        print(f"Action after clipping: {action}")

        # Apply action to simulation
        data.ctrl[:] = action

        # Step simulation
        try:
            mujoco.mj_step(model, data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred during simulation step: {e}")
            break

        # Check for invalid simulation state
        if np.any(np.isnan(data.qpos)) or np.any(np.isinf(data.qpos)):
            print(f"Invalid qpos detected at step {step}")
            break

        # Render simulation
        if glfw.window_should_close(window):
            break

        # Update scene and render
        viewport_width, viewport_height = glfw.get_framebuffer_size(window)
        viewport = mujoco.MjrRect(0, 0, viewport_width, viewport_height)
        cam = mujoco.MjvCamera()
        opt = mujoco.MjvOption()
        scene = mujoco.MjvScene(model, maxgeom=10000)
        mujoco.mjv_updateScene(model, data, opt, None, cam, mujoco.mjtCatBit.mjCAT_ALL, scene)
        mujoco.mjr_render(viewport, scene, context)
        glfw.swap_buffers(window)
        glfw.poll_events()

    # Clean up
    glfw.terminate()
    print("Simulation completed successfully.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


